# nginx proxy forwarder for a wordpress container fails with upstream timed out

Tags: wordpress, docker, nginx

I have an nginx running in a docker which acts as https proxy.  I have lot of other services running in other docker containers, like, gitlab and nginx seems to work fine as a web proxy.

Today I setup a wordpress docker and used below config in nginx:

```
#
# A virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
#

server {
    listen       80;
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  x.example.com;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/privkey.pem;

    if ($scheme = http) {
            return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://172.19.0.3;
        proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        # these two lines here
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
    }
}
```

the wordpress is running on host port 8080 and guest port 80.  i.e., i can perfectly access the site with the url http://x.example.com:8080.  But when I try to access using https, i.e, https://x.example.com, nginx gives me **504 Gateway Time-out**.

```
docker logs -f nginx-proxy
```

shows the below log line.

```
2018/04/23 21:52:21 [error] 28#28: *3202 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while connecting to upstream, client:
37.20.24.26, server: x.example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", u 0/", host: "x.example.com"
37.201.224.236 - - [23/Apr/2018:21:52:21 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 504 585 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

Can someone please help me how to fix this issue?  Wordpress is running under a different docker network as the container was created using docker-compose.xml.  Is that the reason that nginx not able to proxy through?

Comment: Well your IP address of your upstream is most likely not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my nginx container was not able to communicate to the docker network created for wordpress.  Resolved the issue using

> docker network connect

command.

Comment: 2023 still it is this helpful. You need to attach the containers to the same network and restart them after this command.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem with local upstream. It was pointing to localhost, which was resolved to both ipv4 and ipv6 while docker made bindings only on ipv4. When request from nginx proxy used ipv6, it timed out (according to connection timeout, default 60s) but retry succeeded (cause it used ipv4).